# Why can't I implicitly cast this object to a class reference

Tags: c#, oop

Can someone please explain why this doesn't work?

```
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
object obj = myClass1;
MyClass myClass2 = obj; <-- error
```

If obj "points" to the same block of memory of type MyClass, then why can I not "point" myClass2 to the same block of memory on the last line?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Waiting for Jon Skeet answer =)

Comment: I do think you have to learn the very basics of a [strongly-typed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing).

Comment: Because the *general* case of `Object -> ClassType` may result in a Cast Exception (not all objects are *viewable* as `ClassType`). The compiler is forcing the cast to be explicit: if you want it, you can get it. While this particular case can be analyzed to show that that `obj` only ever names an instance of `MyClass`, it is a very specific scenario...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of myClass2 is "`MyClass`".  You can assign to it any value that is of a type that is, or derives from, `MyClass`.  `object` is not and does not derive from `MyClass`, so you need a cast.

If it were able to do this implicitly, what would happen if you did it with an object that is not really a `MyClass`?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're saying.  I guess I was getting confused over the idea of object being a "universal" type.  Thanks.

Comment: @user943870 That's what [`dynamic`](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20dynamic%20keyword) would be for.

Answer (score 7):

c# compiler only allows you to implicitly cast from derived class to base class, not the other way around. In your case, you need to explicitly cast from object to Myclass which is the derived class

Answer (score 3):

Because `object` is a *base* class here.

If I have this:

```
class Square : Shape
{
}

class Circle : Shape
{
}
```

I can do

```
Shape c = new Circle();
```

Think about this semantically, a circle **is a** shape. I can store a circle as a shape.

But I can't do:

```
Circle c = new Shape();
```

Because a shape is NOT a circle, it could be a Square. Consider:

```
Shape sq = new Square();
Shape cr = new Circle();
```

According to how you see it, this should then work:

```
Circle x = cr;
```

But without a cast even this should work:

```
Circle x = sq;//this will blow up, sq is a square.
```

Therefore you need a cast. Similarly an `object` could be anything a `Form`, a `Button` or a `MyClass`. You need to cast it so the runtime will throw an exception if it isn't the correct type.

Comment: damit just got interrupted while posting this and I see there are already up-voted accepted answers!

Comment: Good example and makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

C# is a statically typed language.  You indicated that `obj` is of type `object`.  Because the language is statically typed, you can only expect the compiler to respect the explicit type that you've specified for `obj` and complain about the fact that you're trying to treat an `object` as if it were a `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
MyClass myClass2 = myClass1 ;
```

you can directly assign a class of type A to another class of Same type, but not an object with out type because complier doesn't know what type that object is so in that case you need a cast

```
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
object obj = myClass1;
MyClass myClass2 = (MyClass)obj;
```

this will work because `(MyClass)obj;` is telling compiler that obj is of type MyClass